# Finding sender of multicast UDP packet when using WSARecvMsg

Tags: c, windows, sockets, multicast, recvmsg

I am attempting to retrieve the ip of the sender of a multicast packet as well as the destination address/interface to which the multicast packet was sent.

When receiving a multicast packet via `recvfrom(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags, sockaddr *from, int *fromlen)` returns the senders IP via the from parameter, however no information is provided as to the address which the packet is being sent to.

In order to overcome this shortcoming of `recvfrom()` I have attempted to use `WSARecvMsg()` which supposedly provides all the information required. Answers to other questions all seem very confident that all the information required can be acquired using (at least the *nix) recvmsg method.

When receiving a packet with `WSARecvMsg()` and examining the `IN_PKTINFO` structure, it contains the following:

```
typedef struct in_pktinfo {
  IN_ADDR ipi_addr;
  ULONG   ipi_ifindex;
} IN_PKTINFO, *PIN_PKTINFO
```

And from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/ws2ipdef/ns-ws2ipdef-in_pktinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN) the member `ipi_addr` is the destination address and `ipi_ifindex` is the interface on which it was received.

From the above it seems as if `WSARecvMsg()` can only provide the other half (i.e. the destination) but not the senders information.

Am I missing something? Or is there another way to get the information I want, preferably without having to resort to raw sockets?

Comment: Eh? The datagram's source address is received  via the `LPSOCKADDR` member of the `WSAMSG` parameter of `WSARecvMsg()`.

Comment: That is indeed true for a normal UDP packet, however when using multicast the address returned in the `LPSOCKADDR` member is the multicast group address rather than the senders address